# Highcharts callbacks in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Im trying to implement Highcharts for one of the projects.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/
```

It all works fine but not sure how this call is constructed after the callback parameter..When I check in the browser it looks as given below..

--

```
'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=jQuery110208151241965570799_1483548447968&_=1483548447969
```

What is this value -- jQuery110208151241965570799_1483548447968&_=1483548447969

or how it is constructed

Comment: `jQuery110208151241965570799_1483548447968` is the name of the JSONP callback function. `&_=...` is the timestamp appended to prevent the response being cached

Comment: This might help: [Please explain JSONP in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13397751/218196)

Answer (score 0):

I think that jQuery appends a random parameter to the URL when you use a jQuery Ajax call. They do this to create a unique XMLHTTP (Ajax) request to prevent the browser from caching the file. You might want to lookup the jQuery documentation to disable caching or learn more about why and how:

[jQuery Ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)